# How to use model trained with BCEWithLogitsLoss loss function

Tags: pytorch

I am using the `torch.nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss` function to train a binary classification model. This loss function, as quoted from the docs, has already embedded with a `sigmoid` function.

> This loss combines a Sigmoid layer and the BCELoss in one single class. This version is more numerically stable than using a plain Sigmoid followed by a BCELoss as, by combining the operations into one layer, we take advantage of the log-sum-exp trick for numerical stability.

So my question is after training this model, how should I use this model with the new inputs? Can I simply add a `F.sigmoid()` layer after the final layer of my model? But the doc says it is different from using a plain Sigmoid layer with BCELoss.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering you have a trained `model` with [BCEWithLogitsLoss](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss.html), for inference you can simply do:

```
model = your_model()
out = model(test_data)
probs = torch.sigmoid(out)
```

You can checkout this [issue](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/inference-when-output-sigmoid-is-within-bcewithlogitsloss/36522) for further reference.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit vague, but I put this answer based on the assumption that you have a trained model, named `trained_model`, and now you want to classify new data with it. In this case, all you need to do is check if the output is positive or negative:

```
trained_model.eval()
with torch.no_grad():
   output = trained_model(x)
   preds = (output > 0.).float()
```

If you want to see the probabilities for each instance belonging to *class 1*:

```
trained_model.eval()
with torch.no_grad():
   output = trained_model(x)
   probs = torch.sigmoid(ouput)
```